# Jenkins Maven job doesn't use localRepository from settings.xml

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have three `Jenkins` `Maven` jobs:  one that builds and installs dependencies (JARs) and two that use those dependencies to bundle deployable WAR files.

I have configured all the three jobs to use a specific `settings.xml` file and, while not fully understanding the difference between the `Settings file` and `Global Settings file` (even after reading the ?, it's not clear), under **Build** I set both fields to the file path I wish to use, just in case:

[image]

`/opt/maven/conf/settings.xml` specifies:

```
<localRepository>/var/lib/maven/repo</localRepository>
```

however, the dependencies get downloaded in a different location: `/var/lib/jenkins/maven-repositories/1` as `/var/lib/jenkins` is `JENKINS_HOME`.

The console output logs the following:

> Executing Maven:  -B -f /var/lib/code/src/pom.xml -Dmaven.repo.local=/var/lib/jenkins/maven-repositories/2 -s /opt/maven/conf/settings.xml -gs /opt/maven/conf/settings.xml clean install -P depBuild

which is confusing because `maven.repo.local` is different that what the file listed under -s and -gs says it should be.

Why does it not download and install dependencies in the local repo I specify in the settings.xml I tell it to use?

Here is the whole settings.xml:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

  <localRepository>/var/lib/maven/repo</localRepository>

  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>build.tomcat.all</id>
      <username>buildman</username>
      <password>mypass</password>
    </server>
  </servers>


  <pluginGroups></pluginGroups>

  <proxies></proxies>

  <mirrors></mirrors>

  <profiles></profiles>

</settings>
```

Comment: Can you post the full settings.xml? Is there another settings.xml in your source files?

Comment: please see my update

Comment: It looks like Jenkins overrides the local repository using the command line option when executing Maven. The parameter is probably taken from `.m2/settings.xml` in the Jenkins home or installation directory. Can you check that location?

Comment: You can change the default settings.xm in the Global Tool Configuration of Jenkins.

Comment: When you run your job, please check out the console output. It should print what exactly is being run;.The exact line with all the flags and options. Probably you'll see that something gets overriden there and it will help

Comment: @MarkBramnik -- like i updated the question:  `Executing Maven: -B -f /var/lib/code/src/pom.xml -Dmaven.repo.local=/var/lib/jenkins/maven-repositories/2 -s /opt/maven/conf/settings.xml -gs /opt/maven/conf/settings.xml clean install -P depBuild`

Comment: I have somewhat lessened the problem by going to `Manage Jenkins-->Configure System` and changing `Local Maven Repository` to **Local to Workspace**. However, I am still not able to effect the setting from settings.xml

Answer (score 0):

Try configuring it using the [Config File Provider Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Config+File+Provider+Plugin). After installing this plugin, you can create a config file in **Manage Jenkins** > **Managed files** > **Add a new Config** > **Maven settings.xml**.

It also starts you off with a template so you can just modify what you need. I just added the `<localRepository>` tag after the commented explanation about it.

Then in your Maven job, choose "provided settings.xml" and select the config file you just created.

Make sure you don't have any overriding options in `MAVEN_OPTS` and that *"Use private Maven repository"* is not checked.

[image]

**PS:** It doesn't look like you need to do this with "Global settings.xml" - you can leave that as "Use default". My limited understanding is that the global settings affects all users of the maven system, while the non-global one only affects the user that runs maven. I don't think it matters for most projects, but maybe if you have a special project where some shell execution happens under a different user, this could be important. *(I'm just guessing.)*